# file_get_contents api vk выдает false, хотя если вручную зайти - заходит

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Перехожу по ссылке в браузере

```
https://oauth.vk.com/access_token
```

Выдает как и ожидается

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"client_secret is undefined"}
```

Через file_get_contents - выдает false.

```
var_dump( file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token') );// false
```

Где искать ошибку?...

Пробовал так-же через cURL

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image     /webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    "accept-language: uk,ru;q=0.8,en;q=0.6",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 YaBrowser/17.6.1.744 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку: **Could not resolve host: oauth.vk.com**

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую! Нашёл подобный вопрос на toster: [**Curl для oauth.vk.com**](https://toster.ru/q/91813) 
Смысл в том, что нельзя использовать для https - `file_get_content`
Даже если получится, использовать функции всё равно не сможете, и придётся использовать curl.Так что используйте curl сразу! Вот пример функции, из ответа на toster:

```
function get_curl($url) {
    if(function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    } else {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }
}
```

Проверил, на ссылку вида: `get_curl('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token')` возвращает:

```
{
    error: "invalid_client",
    error_description: "client_secret is undefined"
}
```

Comment: Попробовал так, все равно пишет "Could not resolve host: oauth.vk.com". 
Может проблема в настройках сервера думаю, или ДНС..

Comment: @user190134 скорее всего так оно и есть. :)